# Email session expiration date?

Tags: email, accounts, logout

How long should remain an email session opened? Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail. And what's the best practice to expire it?

I looked up for it but with no luck.
Thanks!

Comment: Yahoo you can choose between 1 day or 2 weeks: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN20351.html, Gmail IIRC never timeouts

Comment: 3 days to 2 weeks is a common practice.

Comment: This seems to be a question about either implementation or security. What the UX angle here?

Comment: @AndrewMartin, while what you say is true, there are obvious UX angles in users having open sessions, having to log in / out, usability for processes regarding security measures and so on. As it stands, it's quite *off-topic-ish*, but there are many UX concerns to this answer as well

Comment: The session expiration is a valid UX question. Even though it touches on other topics, it has a directly measurable user impact.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the discussion. For sure there are UX concerns about the time you remain opened a session.

Comment: ...It's vital for example in eCommerce sites where a checkout process with a user already logged is a peace of cake.

Answer (score 1):

If data loss is the result of beeing logged out automatically, always make sure the user is aware of the expiration. For example my bank will remind you on every page that your session will expire in a few minutes. If the user may login any time and resume where he left, the expiration time is not much of a concern. Implement a "Keep me logged in" checkbox and keep the session open for as long as possible when ticked. This implicitly gives the user a hint that if he does not tick the checkbox, the session will expire when he leaves the page. Keep it open for a few days (3 days to 2 weeks, as stated in the comments).